# Hibernate Field Naming with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

In my table I have columns with the following names `price_year_2023_eur` , `date_added`, `yet_another_column_2`, ....
On the `kotlin` side I want to be able to use `camelCase` column names. Because of that I am trying to convert the column names.

```
// kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Project(
    @Column var priceYear2023Eur : String = "",
    @Column var dateAdded: Int = 1,
    @Column var name: String = "",
    @Column var yetAnotherColumn2: Double = 0.0,
)
```

I created a class (based on [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy#physical_name)) in which I extend the `convertToSnakeCase()` to include numbers.

```
class CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy {
    fun toPhysicalCatalogName(identifier: Identifier, jdbcEnv: JdbcEnvironment?): Identifier? {
        return convertToSnakeCase(identifier)
    }

    fun toPhysicalColumnName(identifier: Identifier, jdbcEnv: JdbcEnvironment?): Identifier? {
        return convertToSnakeCase(identifier)
    }

    fun toPhysicalSchemaName(identifier: Identifier, jdbcEnv: JdbcEnvironment?): Identifier? {
        return convertToSnakeCase(identifier)
    }

    fun toPhysicalSequenceName(identifier: Identifier, jdbcEnv: JdbcEnvironment?): Identifier? {
        return convertToSnakeCase(identifier)
    }

    fun toPhysicalTableName(identifier: Identifier, jdbcEnv: JdbcEnvironment?): Identifier? {
        return convertToSnakeCase(identifier)
    }

    private fun convertToSnakeCase(identifier: Identifier): Identifier? {
        val regexCamelCase = "([a-z])([A-Z])".toRegex()
        val regexNumber = """([a-zA-Z])(\d)""".toRegex()
        val replacement = "$1_$2"
        val newNameLetters: String = identifier.text
            .replace(regexCamelCase, replacement)
            .lowercase()
        val newNameNumbers: String = newNameLetters
            .replace(regexNumber, replacement)
            .lowercase()
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(newNameNumbers)
    }
}
```

This class I added to the `application.properties` files like this

```
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org....utils.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

However, I am getting

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column p1_0.price_year2023eur does not exist
> Hinweis: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "p1_0.price_year_2023_eur".

Something is not working with the conversion, and I am unsure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. With Spring boot 3 and Hibernate 6, `application.properties` must look like this

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=<path>.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Note that *physical-strategy* uses a `CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy` and not the shipped `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the conversion from camelCase to snake_case you have to set this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

Or if you want to use your own:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org....utils.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

**Please not that there is spring.jpa before hibernate...**

And finally `CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy` MUST implement `PhysicalNamingStrategy` from Hibernate.

Comment: This does not handle numbers in column names. When there is something like `price_year_2023_eur` it does convert it into `price_year2023eur`. This is why I wrote my own one. Why can't I use my selfwritten one?

Comment: @four-eyes I've updated my answer. Please not that your property name was wrong

Comment: I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Your CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy does not implement PhysicalNamingStrategy !

Comment: That is correct, however, it is still not working. When I try this `@Column(name ="year_2022_green") var year2022Green: String = "";` it works... Can hibernate not work with numbers in column names with a `CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy` or `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`?

Comment: Numbers are not considered as upper or lower case and therefore nothing happens

Comment: I accounted for that in my custom `convertToSnakeCase()`

Comment: Have you tried to debug your naming strategy?

Comment: I answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with hibernate, Then you can use `name` attribute of `@Column` annotation just like you did in `@Table`. e.g.

```
@Column(name = "year_2022_green")
var year2022Green: String = "";
```

Comment: I do not want to set this for every column... I want to set it once globally!